# Mongoid Query Syntax Question

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I need to retrieve a set of answers according to 2 attributes.

This is what i want to do:

```
# where liker_ids is an array and user_id is a bson in the answer document
feed_answers=Answer.any_in(:liker_ids=>to_use,:user_id.in=>to_use).desc()map{|a|a}
```

What i ended up doing:

```
# to use 
to_use=[some array of ids]
friend_answers=Answer.any_in(:liker_ids=>to_use).map{|a|a}
liked_answers=Answer.where(:user_id.in=>to_use).map{|a|a}

feed_answers=(friend_answers+ liked_answers).sort{|x,y| y.created_at<=>x.created_at}
```

The problem is that I do not not know how to combine the 2 queries into one. I have been trying out various combinations, but nothing seems to work. and my hacked together method is highly inefficient of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do(Missing parameter to `desc`):

```
Answer.any_in(:liker_ids=>to_use, :user_id.in=>to_use).desc(:created_at)
```

But the [any_in](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_in) here is not correctly used, it behaves similar to `where` in this situation. You probably want `or`:

```
Answer.or(:liker_ids=>to_use).or(:user_id.in=>to_use).desc(:created_at)
# or
Answer.any_of({:liker_ids=>to_use}, {:user_id.in=>to_use}).desc(:created_at)
# or
Answer.or({:liker_ids=>to_use}, {:user_id.in=>to_use}).desc(:created_at)
```

You don't need that `map` at the end of criteria chain, mongoid criteria are lazy loaded, when they encounter a method which criteria do not respond to. They can also leverage mongodb cursors, so it is advised not to use map if it is not necessary. You should use `Criteia#only` or `Criteria#without` if you want to retrieve subset of fields from mongodb.

Comment: Answer.or throws an error (undefined method `or' for Answer:Class)

Comment: this one ended up working, thanks! 

feed_answers=Answer.any_of({:liker_ids.in=>to_use}, {:user_id.in=>to_use}).desc(:created_at).skip(to_skip).limit(per_page)

Comment: @ming yellow If you want the or to work, you would need to change `Answer.or` to `Answer.all.or`. I am not sure why, but or hasn't been exposed directly for the model, works fine if you already have a criteria though.